# Sonarqube - documented API configuration

Tags: java, javadoc, sonarqube

I use sonarqube 4.3.2 for java project.
Is there any way to configure sonarqube settings when checking javadoc for public API? Right now all uncodumented public classes/methods/constructors are checked for javadoc. I would like to skip checking on default constructors and setters/getters.

Answer (score 1):

By default undocumentedAPI check should skip setters and getters.

There are unfortunately no configuration available for this rule, so only way is to deactivate it alltogether or mark issues as false positive.

Comment: In my project setters and getters are counted as undocumented API. And I think undocumented API and issues are separated. I have a class without any issue but with undocumented API, and can't see any way to mark this as false positive.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up metric and issue. But nonetheless, accessors should be excluded from this metric.